# Covariance matrix between 2 assets over a specific time horizon

Tags: r, covariance-matrix

I have to compute the inverse of the covariance matrix [variance covariance covariance variance] between 2 assets (SPY and TLT) over the time horizon 2006 2010
I did this

```
ret1=diff(SPY1) %2006-31/12/2009 of log of SPY
ret2=diff(TLT1)
dim(ret1)
dim(ret2)
dim(m1)
dim(r1)
m1 = t(m1)
r1 = t(r1)
inv_C = matrix(0,nrow = NCOL(ret1),ncol = 1)

for(i in 1:NCOL(ret1)) {
  cov1 = cov(ret1[,i],ret2[,i])
  inv_C[i,] = 1/cov1
}
```

but this give me only a single value for each I need all the matrix
HOW can I do that? Thanks

Comment: please provide a reproducible data set. But I think  u can just do `cov(ret1, ret2)` to get the covariance matrix

Comment: You can calculate a covariance matrix between two variables by giving the matrix of the two variables as an argument to cov. E.g. `cov1 = cov(cbind(ret1, ret2))`. Its inverse matrix can be obtained by `solve(cov1)`. (If for some reason you want to get element-wise inverses of `cov1`, you can get them by `cov1^-1`.)

Comment: no I don't have to do the only covariance but build up a variance covariance matrix

Comment: I answered  with a new post below

Comment: Tommaso, you should edit your original question to include your explanation you have included as an answer. That way others will not think that you have answered your own question. I see that your `dim(ret1) = dim(ret2) = 1006 x 252`. I suspect that these should be 1258 x 1? After the objects are of correct dimension, you can use `cov(cbind(ret1, ret2))`.